# <audio> tag in Firefox not loading HTTPS content - (HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported)

Tags: html, html5-audio, audio-streaming, shoutcast, internet-radio

When using Firefox to load a live MP3 stream over HTTPS using the following code:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://hostname:port/;" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The content will not play and I get this is the web console:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported
```

But if I try the same over an HTTP (not HTTPS) the content plays correctly:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://hostname:port/;" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The HTTP and HTTPS streams are on different servers.

I have checked the MIME types by adding the following in mime.conf and it hasn't made a difference:

```
AddType audio/mpeg mpga mp2 mp2a mp3 m2a m3a
```

Other browsers are fine, appears to just be Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's with the semicolon?  Are you trying to load a SHOUTcast stream or something?

Comment: @Brad Yes, correct

Comment: Then, how are you  using HTTPS?  And, where are you adding these MIME types?

Comment: @Brad I have set up the server to stream over HTTPS which works fine, my problem is with Firefox. I added them to the mime.conf file

Comment: As far as I know, SHOUTcast doesn't support HTTPS, so what server are you using?  Apache?  Your problem definitely isn't client-side.  Other browsers are being nice to you, rolling with whatever the content type.